# Is booting only a part of OS possible?

Tags: operating-systems, security

I am reading the paper HyperEnclave. I have a few questions about the OS in general.

1. Is is safe to assume that attackers cannot mount physical attacks during boot process of the OS?
2. Can we assume that the OS is benign during boot process?
3. Is it possible to remove some parts of the OS and disable DMA capability of peripherals before IOMMU is enabled? Wouldn't doing so require many software changes?

Comment: It's possible on some hardware to boot an operating system on a machine with no attached storage, over a network. Fair to say that there are probably physical attacks you can mount on this. https://networkboot.org/fundamentals/

Comment: Thanks for the info. If were to enable the DMA after booting, would it run as expected? I just don't understand how we can trust the OS before booting and then decide to not trust it later.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.